# Error after loading new plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, pyqt5

In QGIS 3.4, after creating a plugin with plugin builder, compiling it with `pb_tools`, I still can't load it to QGIS. I keep getting the following error message:

> "Couldn't load plugin 'test_api' due to an error when calling its
>   classFactory() method  ImportError: PyQt4 classes cannot be imported
>   in QGIS 3.x. Use PyQt5 or the version independent qgis.PyQt import
>   instead."

I've already tried to search for the answer here but no success.

Here is how my `.bat` file looks like

```
@ECHO OFF 

set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64

set PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%PATH% 
set PATH=%PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\7-Zip

@echo off 
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat" 
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qt5_env.bat" 
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\py3_env.bat" 
@echo off 
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-dev\bin;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-7.2.2\lib;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-7.2.2\bin;%PATH%

cd /d %~dp0

::start cmd
```

I guess the other setups are correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And ? are sure your plugin is not calling **PyQt4** ?

Comment: It was in resources.py. I took a look at a functional 3.4 plugin and copied a similiar import, but still can't run.

Comment: Is it just the imports or class references and calls? I'm not sure how to find out

Comment: if your code is calling PyQt4 i fear QGIS (3 and later) won't agree with that ...

Comment: I understand, but i'm not sure which lines I have to change besides "From PyQt4.imports", It's a simple plugin generated by the latest version of Plugin Buider. I didn't actually code yet.

Comment: sorry i don't know what plugin builder is generating ... but switching from Qt4 to QT5 can imply to change a few lines too ...

Comment: I'll try to make a few changes here. Tks

Comment: but the key doesn't seem to be in your configuration have more a look in the plugin code and see where these Qt4 calls are coming from ..

Answer (score 1):

Solved that calling:

```
qt5_env
py3_env
pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc
```

I ran directly in my plugin folder. Apparently it modifies `resources.py` file to work with `PyQt5`. If the above commands generates a `resources_rc` file instead of altering the original, just copy the contents from `resources_rc.py` to `resources.py` or change the call from your main `.py` file. I'm not if that's best way but it worked for me.